# SVN stop asking for username + password

Tags: ubuntu, svn

With an SVN commit with specified username and password. I want the server to throw an error; so I can tell my user that he got her/his password wrong.

Instead, after the commit with the wrong password:

```
svn commit "test_file.txt" --username admin --password abc
```

I get:

```
Authentication realm: <http://svn:80> Subversion Repository
Username:
```

And it keeps asking for a `Username:` and `Password:`. Is there a setting to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`--non-interactive`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.non_interactive) will do this:

> Disables all interactive prompting. **Some examples of interactive prompting include requests for authentication credentials** and conflict resolution decisions. This is useful if you're running Subversion inside an automated script and it's more appropriate to have Subversion fail than to prompt for more information.

(emphasis mine) and it sounds like you're scripting the SVN command line client so you'd want this more generally anyway.

Comment: It seems a logical thing to do, but the commit fails; `svn: E205001: Cannot invoke editor to get log message when non-interactive`

Comment: Adding a message `-m "..."` [solves the problem](http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/forum/opensource-subversion-forums/general-setup-and-troubleshooting/linux-unix-servers/6219-svn-copy-using-non-interactive)